# Disable page on Javascript submit (during file download)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've looked and don't see any way to disable the page, like an overlay on the page to prevent any action when I have a JavaScript submit action:

```
 function AgendaMinutes() {
    var id = '@Model.ID';
    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="AgendaMinutes">');
    form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="dprid" value="' + id + '">'));
    $(body).append(form);
    form.submit().remove();
    return false;
}
```

This works like a charm in generating and sending a PDF to the client, but allows the user to click the button more than once.  I could disable the button but how do I know when the PDF has been returned so that I can release it?

Comment: Why don't you create the overlay like this ?http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp

Comment: from experience, this is can be a pain to make work reliably cross browser - chrome can be a real PITA (at least, it was 2 years ago)

Comment: It's not clear how you're "sending a PDF to the client" - the easiest option is to do so in a new window/tab, then they get a progress indicator (in the browser) and your page doesn't need to know when it's completed (as the other tab handles it).

Comment: you can use blockui js infact http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes!  I had forgotten about performing the post with the target of _blank, which opens a new tab.  This works perfectly in that the new tab pops up and goes away when the download has arrived.  Give me a solution so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how do I know when the PDF has been returned [so that I can re-enable the page]

The simplest option for downloading a file and "knowing" when it is complete is to send the file to a new window/tab via `target="_blank"`.

This way, the user gets a progress indicator (via the browser) and your page doesn't need to know when it's completed (as the other tab handles it) so can be be re-enabled immediately.

If your page needs to wait for some reason, eg the document must be generated before continuing, then an alternative solution would be require: in this case, I'd generate *and persist* the file on the server, then provide a download link to the client.